# How to get this list of value in SQL Server 2008 (FIFO Related)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

| Batch Number | ITEM Number | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00980001 | 0098 | 100 |
| 00980002 | 0098 | 225 |
| 00980003 | 0098 | 150 |
| 01020004 | 0098 | 90 |
| 01020005 | 0098 | 80 |
| 01020006 | 0098 | 115 |

1. If I want to take item 0098 from the earliest batch number to fulfil my needs of 85 qty, how can I achieve that ?

   The output should be like this

   | Order Number | Batch Number | ITEM Number | Qty |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | AA0001 | 00980001 | 0098 | 85 |
2. I want to take another 127 pcs of item 0098 in the next order and i want the output become like this :

   | Order Number | Batch Number | ITEM Number | Qty |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | AA0002 | 00980001 | 0098 | 15 |
   | AA0002 | 00980002 | 0098 | 112 |

Comment: Have you try anything ?

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for well over 3.5 years; it is *really8 long past time you got your upgrade path finalised and implemented now.

Comment: i knew it but i have a case in sql server 2008 and upgrading it still dont answer the problem tho :/

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to insert a row or rows, update a row or rows?  Where does the 85 come from?

Comment: 85 is the request value , i want to get the result to insert it into another table

Answer (score 0):

I think he's writing a warehouse fulfillment system.

I'd use two cursors.
One cursor loops all order rows. In it, another cursor loops your items where Qty > 0.
For each inner item, you take the quantity you have and decrease the amount items left. If you fulfilled whole order row, you jump out, otherwise you continue on next batch.

Something like this:

```sql
create table #t_orders (orderid int, itemid int, qty int, qty_fulfilled INT primary key (orderid, itemid))
create table #t_skus (itemid int, qty int, batchnumber VARCHAR(10) primary key (itemid, batchnumber))
create table #t_fulfill (orderid int, itemid int, qty int, batchnumber varchar(10) primary key (orderid, itemid, batchnumber))


insert into #t_orders (orderid, itemid, qty)
select 1, 1001, 10
union
select 2, 1001, 3
union
select 2, 1002, 15

insert into #t_skus (itemid, qty, batchnumber)
select 1001,10, 'A001'
union
select 1001,30, 'A002'
union
select 1002,99, 'A004'

declare @itemid int, @orderid int, @qty int, @qty_batch int, @qty_left int, @batch varchar(10)


declare cr_x cursor for select orderid, itemid, qty from #t_orders order by orderid, itemid
open cr_x

while 1 = 1
begin
    fetch next from cr_x into @orderid, @itemid, @qty
    if @@fetch_status <> 0
        break

    -- Initially all is left
    set @qty_left = @qty
    
    declare cr_y cursor for
        select  qty, batchnumber
        FROM    #t_skus t
        where   t.itemid = @itemid
        and t.qty > 0
        order by batchnumber
    open cr_y
    while 1 = 1
    begin
        fetch next from cr_y into @qty_batch, @batch
        if @@fetch_status <> 0
            break

        declare @qty_taken INT = case when @qty_batch > @qty_left THEN @qty_left ELSE @qty_batch END

        insert into #t_fulfill (orderid, itemid, qty, batchnumber)
        SELECT  @orderid, @itemid, @qty_taken, @batch 

        update #t_skus -- decrease taken quantity
        set qty = qty - @qty_taken
        where current of cr_y

        -- Update order table just in case
        update #t_orders
        set qty_fulfilled = ISNULL(qty_fulfilled, 0) + @qty_taken
        where current of cr_x

        set @qty_left = @qty_left - @qty_taken

        print @qty_left

        if @qty_left = 0 -- if done, we can jump out
            break
        
    end
    close cr_y
    deallocate cr_y
end

close cr_x
deallocate cr_x

select *
from #t_fulfill
select *
from #t_orders
select *
from #t_skus


drop table #t_orders
drop table #t_fulfill
drop table #t_skus
```

Comment: sorry for late reply , i will try this very soon and . thanks for the answer

Comment: @DBNoob99 did you have time to try it yet?